# A Borel-Cantelli Type Statement

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal X, \mu)$ be a probability space and $E_1, E_2, E_3, \ldots$ be measurable sets such that there is $\varepsilon>0$ satisfying $\mu(E_i)\geq \varepsilon$ for each $i$.

> **Question.** Is is true that infinitely many of the $E_i$'s occur with positive probability, or, in other words, is it true that $\mu(\limsup E_n) > 0$?

If the $E_i$'s were pairwise independent then we know that answer is yes by Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: I think this might answer your question: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3213220

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is true: Let $S = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \chi_{E_i}$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $S < \infty$ a.e. Then, there exists an $M$ such that $\Pr(S\le M) \ge 1 - \frac\varepsilon 2$. If $A$ is the event that $S\le M$,  then $\mu(A\cap E_i) \ge \frac\varepsilon 2$ for all $i$. But this would imply $\int_A S\,d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(A\cap E_i) = \infty$, which is impossible because $S\le M$ on $A$.

Comment: You mean $S=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \chi_{E_i}$?

Answer (score 0):

I think an affirmative answer follows from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Kochen%E2%80%93Stone

The $\sum P(A_n) = \infty$ condition is clear. To verify the lim inf, we note that $(\sum_{n = 1}^k P(A_n))^2 \geq \epsilon^2 k^2$ and $\sum_{1 \leq m,n \leq k } P(A_m \cap A_n) \leq k^2 $, so that $\frac{ \sum_{1 \leq m,n \leq k } P(A_m \cap A_n) }{( \sum \mathbb{P}(A_n) )^2} \leq \frac{k^2}{k^2 \epsilon^2} = 1/\epsilon^2 < \infty$.

Comment: Is the following a viable argument? Create indicator random variables $\mathbf1_{E_k}$ and couple them in any arbitrary way with a uniform random variable $U\sim\mathscr U(0,1)$. Any such a coupling will always give a positive probability that infinitely many $\mathbf1_{E_k}$ equal 1 because each indicator RV is assigned a region in (0,1) with probability $\epsilon$ or larger. There will always be a region with positive probability in such a coupling which overlaps with infinitely many of these such "$\geq\epsilon$"-regions. The $P(E_k \ io)$ must be preserved by such a coupling.